# Integral of a function with uniform kernel

Tags: kernel-smoothing, mathematical-statistics, integral

I am trying to understand question 9-1 on p.334 in Cameron & Trivedi ([link](http://www.centroportici.unina.it/centro/Cameron&Trivedi.pdf)) where I have to calculate the bias of a kernel density estimate at $x=1$ and $n=100$, where we assume that the underlying density is standard normally distributed, $N(0,1)$. The kernel is uniform, that is we have

$$K(v)=0.5 \times 1(|v|<1)$$

where $v$ is defined as $(x_i-x)/h$ and $\mathbf1$ is the indicator function, that is either $1$ if its argument is true and $0$ otherwise; $h$ is the bandwidth, given to be $1.0$ in this example.

The bias of the kernel is then "simply" obtained as

$$\text{bias} = 0.5h^2f''(x)\int v^2 K(v)dv$$

This doesn't seem to difficult at first. I know $h$, I can calculate $f''(1)$ from the normal distribution analytically.

However, I am stuck on finding $\int v^2 K(v)dv$.

Is there a standard trick, a table or anything that can help me calculating it? I could do it numerically but I believe it should be possible to do it analytically too.

ps this is not a homework question, just curiosity how to apply Kernel density estimates without relying on numerical computations.

Comment: I answered my own question though already. So, it's not really necessary and it's a stupid question. Now I am stuck at something else. At the inflexion point x=1, the bias must be zero right? This is because f''(1)=0 and thus the bias disappears?

Comment: I don't think it's a stupid question. It's a simple question, but that's not at all the same thing; it may still be very useful to later readers, if the question is clear enough. I'll fix it myself.

Comment: ok. Do you understand my other question? Does the bias at x=1 for a standard normal distribution become zero since f''(1)=0? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, the bias formula you give is a function of $x$, and $x$ only enters there via $f''(x)$, so if that's zero the bias must be zero.

Comment: Someone else mentioned it converges as h^4 but did not give any details. That's why I am confused. Note, however, the bias stems from a Taylor expansion of f(hv+x) around x, so it may be that this becomes zero not entirely true... Intuitively I believe the bias must be zero as there is no inflexion at x=1 for the standard normal distb.

Comment: That would be a lot of more to explain, I'd have to roll out all the nonparametric theory of density estimation. The bias is a formal shortcut for iid data and a cutoff of the Taylor expansion after f''(x). This is pretty basic and widely used in the literature. If someone knows their way around nonparametric density estimation he or she would know how to answer this question.

Answer (score 3):

I posted that question on math exchange too as it seems more to be maths related. Well, anyhow it seem that this is indeed trivial as shown by a another user.

As the Kernel is 1 within the Integral, you apparently just integrate

$$0.5 \int v^2 dv $$ between -1 and 1 and end up with 1/3.

I was confused how exactly to treat a Kernel under an integral and thought it was going to be more complex with chain rules etc.

Secondly, at x=1, the second derivative of the standard normal distribution is zero. Hence, the bias is zero regardless of h or the choice of Kernel.